# Porblem with game once builded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

in my game to pass from one level to another you must answer some questions. Each question has an associated image. For each level of play there is a different set of questions. During the Unity game simulation there is no problem, but when I play the build of the game, the set of questions is not updated between one level and another, in fact the last question made at the first level is re-proposed.

```
public class MiniGameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Question[] questions;    
    private static List<Question> unanswered; 
    private Question currentQuestion; 
    [SerializeField]
    private Image sprite; 

    [SerializeField]
    private float timeQuestion = 1f; 

    public static int contCorrect; 
    public Button firstSelected; 

    void Start()
    {
        if(unanswered == null || unanswered.Count == 0) 
        {
            unanswered = questions.ToList<Question>();
        }
        contCorrect = 0; 
        SetCurrentQuestion(); 
        firstSelected.Select();
    }   

    void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
        int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, unanswered.Count);
        currentQuestion = unanswered[index]; 

        sprite.sprite = currentQuestion.questionSprite; 
    }

    IEnumerator ToQuestion()
    {
        unanswered.Remove(currentQuestion); 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeQuestion); 
        SetCurrentQuestion(); 
    }

    public void UserSelectFirst()
    {
        if (currentQuestion.answer == 0) 
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = true; 
            countCorrect++;
        }
        else 
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = false;            
        }
        if (unanswered.Count > 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToQuestion());
        }
        else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, LoadSceneMode.Single); 
        }       
    }

    public void UserSelectSecond()
    {
        if (currentQuestion.answer == 1)
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = true;
            countCorrect++;         
        }
        else
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = false;            
        }
        if (unanswered.Count > 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToQuestion());
        }
        else
        {           
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, LoadSceneMode.Single); 
        }
    }

    public void UserSelectThird()
    {
        if (currentQuestion.answer == 2)
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = true;
            countCorrect++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = false;
        }
        if (unanswered.Count > 1) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToQuestion());
        }
        else
        {           
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }

    public void UserSelectFourth()
    {
        if (currentQuestion.answer == 3)
        {
            currentQuestion.correct = true;
            countCorrect++;
        }
        else 
        {
        currentQuestion.correct = false;
        }
        if (unanswered.Count > 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToQuestion());
        }
        else 
        {           
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, LoadSceneMode.Single);             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just had to clear the list of questions before moving to the next level